# Razor Pages Viewing Foreign Key Attribute Value in Index Page

Tags: c#, html, database, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I connected the City attribute in Person class to CityList class. In create page, I'm populating the City dropdownlist from database values pf CityList class. I can assign and view the CityName in Details, Edit and Delete pages but I cannot see the CityName value in my Index page. I added screenshots of Index page and Details page from browser (at the end) What's missing?

### My Model page

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int CityId { get; set; }

        public virtual CityList City { get; set; }
 
    }
    
    public class CityList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Şehir")]
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
```

### My Index.cshtml page

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.People) {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City.CityName)
                    </td>
                <tr/>
            }
```

[Index page in action(CityName should be in red circle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFst5.png)

[Meanwhile, you can see the CityName in Details page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uhYM.png)

Comment: Did you use an Include method to load the navigational property in your database query for the Index page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: I actually added Include in Details, Edit and Delete.cshtml.cs files but not in Index.cshtml.cs. And I don't know how to add it. Can you help me, i'm really new and amateur in this field. I can upload the needed code parts if you want

Comment: You'd want something like: People.Include( p=>p.City)  (Include the code for index.cs in your post for specific details...)